Why does the protagonist smile while holding the baby at the end of Azrael: Angel of Death?
In the ending of Azrael: Angel of Death (2024), the protagonist (played by Samara Weaving) mysteriously smiles while holding the cult leader's baby, suggesting this might have been her plan all along. What's the meaning behind this scene?
During the film's climax, the cult leader gives birth but recoils in horror at her newborn before taking her own life by slitting her throat. The baby is revealed to be a goat-like demon creature, which the protagonist then picks up while displaying an unsettling smile.
While watching the nearly dialogue-free film, I had no indication that the protagonist was actually Azrael (as revealed in the credits). In religious mythology, Azrael is known as God's angel of death, but there's no traditional association between Azrael and demons or fallen angels, as far as I can tell. This made the protagonist's apparent joy at caring for a demon child puzzling to me, especially since throughout the film, she seemed to be on the side of good (i.e., not the demons).
The story takes place after the Rapture, an event in some Christian denominations' beliefs where the faithful are taken to heaven during the apocalypse. Is there perhaps a connection between this setting and the protagonist's true motives? Could the film be drawing from or subverting specific Christian beliefs about the Rapture?
Why would Azrael, traditionally an angel of death, seem so pleased about ensuring this demonic baby's birth? Was this her intention from the beginning?

https://thedirect.com/article/azrael-2024-ending-explained-baby-who
